Why is the current source in the harmonic model of a circuit with a non-linear load placed at this specific location in the circuit?
I'm studying the harmonic modeling of non-linear loads and came across a simplified schematic representing the non-linear load as a current source and an equivalent impedance (at a certain harmonic frequency). The original circuit includes an AC source, a non-linear load, a capacitor bank, and a linear load. The equivalent circuit eliminates the AC source (since it only operates on a single specific frequency), and replaces the non-linear load with a current source ℎ and equivalent impedance .
Here’s the part that I’m trying to understand: in the equivalent circuit, the current source
ℎ is placed after the parallel combination of

​
,
, and
. Intuitively, I would have expected the current source to be placed directly in front of the inductance
 ​
since it is the non-linear load itself that draws the harmonic currents.
My question is: Why is the current source
ℎ placed at that specific location in the equivalent circuit, rather than directly in front of

?

​
